# JavaScript Regex Test and Replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to sanitize some chars.  I have a solution that works but I am wondering if there is a better solution that may be faster or better or if I flat out should be approaching this differently?

```
function escapeStr(_str){
    if (/\"|\'|\%/g.test(_str)) {
        _str = _str.replace(/"/g, "%22");
        _str = _str.replace(/'/g, "%27");
        _str = _str.replace(/%/g, "%25");
    }
    return _str;
}
```

And vice versa:

```
function unescapeStr(_str){
    if (/\%22|\%27|\%25/g.test(_str)) {
        _str = _str.replace(/\%22/g, '"');
        _str = _str.replace(/\%27/g, "'");
        _str = _str.replace(/\%25/g, "%");
    }
    return _str;
}
```

Comment: Why the if clause? Why not just replace, even if there are no matches?

Comment: Could you provide some context about what you want to accomplish?  Why do you want to handle those three characters specially?

Comment: Yes, I have issues with a specific database collation and this is for a hybrid app. Some browsers are giving me an _str.replace(...) is an undefined function, but when I test for it specifically it works.

Comment: What collation? What issues? Sounds like it could be a known problem with an existing solution.

Comment: If it's telling you that `replace` is undefined, it's because you trying to use it when on a `_str` value that isn't a string. You can replace the `test` call with `typeof _str === 'string'`, and it should work the same. The problem is: Why is `_str` sometimes not a string... Anyway, that's all irrelevant, since, as abl said, this sounds like a known problem

Comment: Thanks all.  I just learned that this is great place to get really good opinions and hints on my code.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding the characters, and their escape values specifically in your [`.replace`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/replace) call, you can pass a callback function for the replacement. I suggested that you dive into [`encodeURI`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/encodeuri):

So, something like:

```js
function escapeStr(_str) {
  return _str.replace(/([%'"])/g, encodeURI)
}

function unescapeStr(_str) {
  return _str.replace(/(%(?:2[257]))/g, decodeURI)
}
const e = escapeStr, u = unescapeStr;
console.log( e("string") );
console.log( e("some\" char%s") );
console.log( u("string") );
console.log( u("some%22 char%25s") );
```

Answer (score 0):

In first and second function

```
function escapeStr(_str){
    if (/\"|\'|\%/g.test(_str)) { // unnecessary if 
        _str = _str.replace(/"/g, "%22"); // unnecessary asigment
        _str = _str.replace(/'/g, "%27"); // unnecessary asigment
        _str = _str.replace(/%/g, "%25"); // unnecessary asigment
    }
    return _str;
}
```

You can add if (value) this will prevent errors while passing null of something like this

This probably more complex and optimal:

```
const escapeStr = str => str ? str
  .replace(/%/g, "%25")
  .replace(/"/g, "%22")
  .replace(/'/g, "%27") : str

const unescapeStr = str => str ? str
  .replace(/\%25/g, "%")  
  .replace(/\%22/g, '"')
  .replace(/\%27/g, "'") : str
```

And if we want to go crazy use this:

```
const escapeStr = str => str ? str.replace(/[%'"]/g, encodeURI) : str

const unescapeStr = str => str ? str.replace(/\(%2[257])/g, decodeURI) : str

const testData = [`"hello"`,`'world'`,`2%3`,``, `xyz`, `%22hello%22`]

for (const data of testData) {
  console.log(`${data}:`)
  console.log(`escapeStr -> ${escapeStr(data)}`)
  console.log(`escapeStr -> ${unescapeStr(data)}`)
}
```